# Gradle fails when run in docker container

Tags: java, docker, gradle, code-generation, jooq

I am using Gradle and it works fine, except when I run it in a docker container. I use the jOOQ code generator. The generated source files are in `build/generated-src/jooq`, but the when building in the docker container, the *compileJava* task fails. I get compilation errors as the generated sources were not compiled, as an example:

```
/home/gradle/src/src/main/java/test/service/UserService.java:4: error: 
package test.database.mydb.tables.records does not exist
import test.database.mydb.tables.records.UserRecord;
```

In both occasions Gradle version *6.0.1* was used.

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM gradle:jdk11 as build-stage
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src
RUN gradle clean build
```

My build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'nu.studer.jooq' version '3.0.3'
}

[...]

sourceSets.main.java.srcDir new File(buildDir, '/generated-src/jooq') // adding the generated sources of jooq folder to the main source set

jooq {
    version = '3.12.3'
    edition = 'OSS'
    database(sourceSets.main) {
        generator {
            database {
                [...]
            }
            target {
                packageName = 'me.mtte.code.ideahub.database'
                directory = new File(buildDir, '/generated-src/jooq') // the output directory
                clean = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why there is a difference between with and without docker container?

Comment: Why not ask the [plugin developer](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin)?

Comment: Hmm... shouldn't be a problem related to the plugin as the code generation works perfectly. The compileJava task is somehow not aware of the source files that have been generated.

Comment: Have you verified that the classes are, in fact, generated during compilation in the container?

Comment: They are generated but I don't think that they are then compiled, thus the error

Comment: @xooback Did you manage to fix this problem? I think I am having a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140023/jooq-unable-to-find-database-when-triggered-via-a-gradle-pluggin-inside-a-docker the source generation is not working for me when gradle runs from docker